Ojet is introduced in our application and the page loads correctly on the local system but not on the server
Through automated scripts, in Chrome Some ojet-related pages are not loading on the server machine,
When we manually load the application, an ojet-related page will load in the server.
And through automation locally also it will load.
Do we need to add any chrome capabilities for this?
